# How to generate JSON data with python 2.7+

Tags: python, json, dictionary

I have to following bit of JSON data which is a snippet from a large file of JSON.
I'm basically just looking to expand this data.
I'll worry about adding it to the existing JSON file later.

The JSON data snippet is:

```
    "Roles": [
  {
    "Role": "STACiWS_B",
    "Settings": {
      "HostType": "AsfManaged",
      "Hostname": "JTTstSTBWS-0001",
      "TemplateName": "W2K16_BETA_4CPU",
      "Hypervisor": "sys2Director-pool4",
      "InCloud": false
    }
  }
],
```

So what I want to do is to make many more datasets of "role" (for lack of a better term)

So something like this:

```
    "Roles": [
  {
    "Role": "Clients",
    "Settings": {
      "HostType": "AsfManaged",
      "Hostname": "JTClients-0001",
      "TemplateName": "Win10_RTM_64_EN_1511",
      "Hypervisor": "sys2director-pool3",
      "InCloud": false
    }
  },
  {
    "Role": "Clients",
    "Settings": {
      "HostType": "AsfManaged",
      "Hostname": "JTClients-0002",
      "TemplateName": "Win10_RTM_64_EN_1511",
      "Hypervisor": "sys2director-pool3",
      "InCloud": false
    }
  },
```

I started with some python code that looks like so, but, it seems I'm fairly far off the mark

```
    import json
    import pprint

Roles = ["STACiTS","STACiWS","STACiWS_B"]
RoleData = dict()
RoleData['Role'] = dict()
RoleData['Role']['Setttings'] = dict()
ASFHostType = "AsfManaged"
ASFBaseHostname = ["JTSTACiTS","JTSTACiWS","JTSTACiWS_"]
HypTemplateName = "W2K12R2_4CPU"
HypPoolName = "sys2director"

def CreateASF_Roles(Roles):
    for SingleRole in Roles:
        print SingleRole #debug purposes
        if SingleRole == 'STACiTS': 
            print ("We found STACiTS!!!") #debug purposes
            NumOfHosts = 1
            for NumOfHosts in range(20): #Hardcoded for STACiTS - Generate 20 STACiTS datasets
                RoleData['Role']=SingleRole
                RoleData['Role']['Settings']['HostType']=ASFHostType
                ASFHostname = ASFBaseHostname + '-' + NumOfHosts.zfill(4)
                RoleData['Role']['Settings']['Hostname']=ASFHostname
                RoleData['Role']['Settings']['TemplateName']=HypTemplateName
                RoleData['Role']['Settings']['Hypervisor']=HypPoolName
                RoleData['Role']['Settings']['InCloud']="false"


CreateASF_Roles(Roles)              

pprint.pprint(RoleData)
```

I keep getting this error, which is confusing, because I thought dictionaries could have named indices.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\CreateASFRoles.py", line 34, in <module>
    CreateASF_Roles(Roles)
  File ".\CreateASFRoles.py", line 26, in CreateASF_Roles
    RoleData['Role']['Settings']['HostType']=ASFHostType
TypeError: string indices must be integers, not str
```

Any thoughts are appreciated.  thanks.

Comment: `RoleData['Role']` isn't a dictionary, it's a string.  Because in the preceding line, you set `RoleData['Role'] = SingleRole`, and `SingleRole` is iterating over a list of strings.

Answer (score 1):

Right here:

```
RoleData['Role']=SingleRole
```

You set RoleData to be the string 'STACiTS'. So then the next command evaluates to:

```
'STACiTS'['Settings']['HostType']=ASFHostType
```

Which of course is trying to index into a string with another string, which is your error. Dictionaries can have named indices, but you overwrote the dictionary you created with a string.

You likely intended to create RoleData["Settings"] as a dictionary then assign to that, rather than RoleData["Role"]["Settings"]

Also on another note, you have another syntax error up here:

```
RoleData['Role']['Setttings'] = dict()
```

With a mispelling of "settings" that will probably cause similar problems for you later on unless fixed.

Comment: Ok thanks.  I knew it had to be some sort of syntax error, but, I've had trouble finding good examples for what I was trying to do.

Comment: Glad I could help! If you wouldn't mind accepting the answer if it helped you, that'd be great!